# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error for duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my code below, I am getting an error:

> The multi-part identifier "i.Inventoryid" could not be bound.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateOrderMultiple
ON tbl_InventoryPolicy
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OldOrderMultiple INT
    DECLARE @NewOrderMultiple INT
    DECLARE @Timestamp DATETIME

    SELECT @OldOrderMultiple = d.ordermultiple
    FROM deleted d
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Inventoryid = d.Inventoryid

    SELECT @NewOrderMultiple = i.ordermultiple
    FROM inserted i

    SET @Timestamp = GETDATE()
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges
            WHERE Inventoryid = i.Inventoryid
            AND OldOrderMultiple = @OldOrderMultiple
            AND NewOrderMultiple = @NewOrderMultiple
        )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges 
                        (InventoryID, OldOrderMultiple, NewOrderMultiple, Timestamp)
            SELECT i.InventoryID, @OldOrderMultiple, 
                    @NewOrderMultiple, @Timestamp
            FROM inserted i
        END
END
```

I want to avoid inserting duplicate entries into the `tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? You can't declare `@` variables in MySQL. And it requires `;` at the end of every statement.

Comment: When I google that error message, all the hits are for SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Presumably this is because you are using `FROM tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges WHERE Inventoryid = i.Inventoryid`. There's no table `i` there, so `i.Inventoryid` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Barmar I think this is MSSQL just because of the "magic tables" `deleted` `inserted`

Comment: @EdmCoff so how do I check if the entry is already in the table and not insert it again?

Comment: @Barmar Yes , I typed MSSQL , it took Mysql and I didn't notice it before posting sorry

Comment: You prevent duplicates by having a [unique constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16). A trigger to remove duplicates _after_ you've inserted them isn't very practical. Also, see [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) and [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I *think* OP is trying to prevent adding duplicates in their change tracking table... having a unique constraint would just blow up the trigger.

Comment: @Dale Ah, I missed `Changes` suffix (probably because I expect most to use, I don't know, change tracking, or CDC, or temporal tables for this instead of reinventing the wheel). But still, even with a unique constraint on the changes table (which should be there if you want to prevent duplicates), it's still just INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS to avoid blowing up the trigger. Anyway, I'm going to leave my comment though because the second half is still pretty relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the classic mistake many people make when it comes to triggers, and that is to suddenly change from regular SQL set-based operations into some sort of procedural logic. Don't do it, continue to use set-based operations as you would for any other query. I think the following converts your existing logic into set-based logic, but you'll need to validate it yourself.

1. Use joins with the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables when required
2. Add a `where` clause to filter out unwanted changes

```
INSERT INTO tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges (InventoryID, OldOrderMultiple, NewOrderMultiple, [Timestamp])
SELECT i.InventoryID, d.ordermultiple, i.ordermultiple, GETDATE()
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN Deleted d on d.InventoryId = i.InventoryId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges
    WHERE Inventoryid = i.Inventoryid
    AND NewOrderMultiple = i.ordermultiple
    AND OldOrderMultiple = d.ordermultiple
);
```

Note: Your trigger is also an insert trigger, but your logic doesn't handle insert because you assume `Deleted` will have rows in it. If it should also handle inserts then the logic needs to be modified to handle no rows in the `Deleted` pseudo table.

I think the following also handles the `INSERT` case, note the `LEFT JOIN` and the null compare:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges (InventoryID, OldOrderMultiple, NewOrderMultiple, [Timestamp])
SELECT i.InventoryID, d.ordermultiple, i.ordermultiple, GETDATE()
FROM Inserted i
LEFT JOIN Deleted d on d.InventoryId = i.InventoryId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_InventoryPolicyChanges c
    WHERE c.Inventoryid = i.Inventoryid
    AND c.NewOrderMultiple = i.ordermultiple
    AND (c.OldOrderMultiple = d.ordermultiple OR (d.ordermultiple IS NULL AND c.OldOrderMultiple IS NULL))
);
```

Comment: Thank you, your code fixed the issue.

Comment: Or the new 2022 syntax `AND (c.OldOrderMultiple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d.ordermultiple)` the double negative really does my head in though